# Gallery can't display image from internal storage

Tags: android

I have image stored in the internal storage of the app. I can grab the path and I can succesfully set it to image view. But when  I am trying to let the user open it using the gallery (intent), it displays black screen.

```
myIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), mimetype);
intent = Intent.createChooser(myIntent, "Choose a viewer");
startActivity(intent);
```

I am pretty sure it has to do with permission that gallery cant access private storage of my app for some reason. But is there way to do that "beside moving the file to external storage"

Thanks

Comment: You can try:  `File file = new File(filePath);
                Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(uri, fileType);
                context.startActivity(intent);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Use `FileProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) to serve the file from [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html). Quoting the documentation:

> FileProvider is a special subclass of ContentProvider that facilitates secure sharing of files associated with an app by creating a content:// Uri for a file instead of a file:/// Uri.
>
> A content URI allows you to grant read and write access using temporary access permissions. When you create an Intent containing a content URI, in order to send the content URI to a client app, you can also call Intent.setFlags() to add permissions. These permissions are available to the client app for as long as the stack for a receiving Activity is active.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easy 'single file based solution'

When ever you add a file, let Media Store Content Provider knows about it using

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE,  
                                       Uri.fromFile(imageAdded)));
```

Answer (score 0):

i have done some thing like this to show images from gallery.

```
private void pickFromGallery() {
    Crop.pickImage(this);
}
```

<--->
crop is an android class.

this is a function in crop class.

```
public static void pickImage(Activity activity) {
    Intent intent = (new Intent("android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT")).setType("image/*");

    try {
        activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 9162);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException var3) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, string.crop__pick_error, 0).show();
    }

}
```